# How to use multibinding on a rectangle-command in mvvm?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, multibinding

I got the following rectangle

```
<Rectangle
    Width="{Binding Width}"
    Height="{Binding Length}"
    Tag="{Binding Id}"
    Name="rectangleDrawnMachine">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger
            EventName="MouseDown">
            <cmd:EventToCommand
                Command="{Binding Main.UpdateSelectedMachine, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
                PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=rectangleDrawnMachine}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```

The rectangle is bound to a model which is declared in an above ItemsControl. The document-structure is like the following:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllMachines}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Name="canvasDrawnMachines" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Name="rectangleDrawnMachine"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Now my *UpdateSelectedMachine*-command needs at least three properties of the rectangle:

- Position x
- Position y
- ID / Tag

With the CommandParameter of the rectangle itself my command will get a lot of informations about the rectangle (like the neccessary tag). But it doesnt get the neccessary information about the (X- & Y-)position of the canvas.

So my question is: how to use multibinding on my rectangle-command? And how to transfer the positions of the canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass multiple values by using command parameter.

In order to do so, you have to use multi binding.

```
<cmd:EventToCommand
            Command="{Binding Main.UpdateSelectedMachine, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
            PassEventArgsToCommand="True">
<cmd:EventToCommand.CommandParameter>
 <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource YourConverter}">
                 <Binding Path="Canvas.Left" ElementName="canvasDrawnMachines"/>
                 <Binding Path="Canvas.Top" ElementName="canvasDrawnMachines"/>
                 <Binding Path="Tag" ElementName="canvasDrawnMachines"/>
 </MultiBinding>
</cmd:EventToCommand.CommandParameter>
```

Your converter:

```
public class YourConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, ...)
    {
        return values.Clone();
    }
}
```

Then, execution command logic:

```
public void OnExecute(object parameter)
{
    var values = (object[])parameter;
    var left = (double)values[0];
    var top = (double)values[1];
    var tag = values[2]; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The multibinding-way works really fine. Problematically the rectangle-position of the canvas doesnt transfer the right value. It says 'not defined'. Maybe because there are multiple rectangles because of my datatemplate?

Comment: It's not the problem with multiple rectangles. You can have it as many as you want. I have updated the bindings in answer.

Comment: Thank you for your update. Problematically e.g. Canvas.Top returns me {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}. The code `<Binding Path="Tag" ElementName="rectangleDrawnMachine" />` works without of problems

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values of the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties of the `Rectangle` that you are passing as the command parameter to the command like this:

```
double x = Canvas.GetLeft(rectangle);
double y = Canvas.GetTop(rectangle);
```

> Do you know how to get the position in XAML-way?

Use a `MultiBinding` with a converter and bind to the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}">
             <Binding Path="(Canvas.Left)" ElementName="canvasDrawnMachines"/>
             <Binding Path="(Canvas.Top)" ElementName="canvasDrawnMachines"/>
             <Binding Path="Tag" ElementName="canvasDrawnMachines"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. But what i want is to do it on XAML with MVVM-pattern. Do you know how to get the position in XAML-way?

Comment: So why are you passing the Rectangle as a parameter to the command? My point is that you can access the coordinates just like you access any other properties of the Rectangle in the Execute method of the command so I don't really understand your issue?

Comment: If you are using a multibinding you should bind to the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties as per my edited answer, i.e. the property is called "Canvas.Left" and not just "Left".

Comment: Thank you for your update. Problematically e.g. Canvas.Top returns me {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}. The coe `<Binding Path="Tag" ElementName="rectangleDrawnMachine" />` works without of problems

Comment: Try to use parentheses around the property name; "(Canvas.Left)".